# Remove bash startup behaviour (mac user)

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, boot, script

When I start the terminal (which uses bash) a echoed message appears several times right before the message "You have mail." and it is added by someone that has used my computer. It also happens when I create a new tab in the terminal.

Now I would like to remove it's appearance, what suggestions do you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it only happens for one user account, check the following files:

- `~/.bash_profile` (and any files `source`d therein)
- `~/.bashrc` (if it exists)
- your `Terminal` preferences: Under the *Startup* tab, is there a command defined to be run when starting Terminal?
- your `Terminal` preferences again: Under the *Settings* tab, check to see if your selected terminal style/configuration defines a startup command under the tab *Shell*.

As per the comments to this post:

- **Check `/etc/motd` to see if a *message of the day* is defined for `login`**

Comment: Crediting the users commenting on [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/224703/script-runs-each-time-i-open-the-terminal).

Comment: Checked the files /etc/profile, /etc/bashrc (no signs leading to any output) and none of ~/.bash_login, ~/.bash_profile or ~/.profile existed. Also checked the preferences in the Terminal application, but no traces of any script running there either.

Comment: @Rikard Change your shell in Terminal preferences, does the problem go away? Use another terminal application, such as iTerm, does the problem go away then?

Comment: @Joey: As I understand the question, the problem is not the message regarding mail, but something repeatedly echoed before that message.

Comment: Changed the shell in the Terminal preferences and also tried with iTerm, both with the same result as before.

Comment: @Rikard Try to see if `login` produces the messages, and check `/etc/motd`, as per `man login`.

Comment: The message text lied in the /etc/motd file! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following

> touch $HOME/.hushlogin

If the message still shows up, it is probably located in one of the bash configuration files.
Check those for an echo or print command.

Comment: The previous question gave a answer to locate where the message came from, but I applied your solution afterwards in order to hide the "You have mail." message. In my case your tip would also have solved the problem.